# Sesión abierta en distintas paginas con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Si uno inicia sesión, el sistema te redirecciona a **/home**, pero si no haz iniciado sesión e intentas ingresar a **/home** te redirecciona a **/login**, entonces, ¿Como hago para que con nuevas paginas creadas suceda lo mismo?
Por ejemplo, si creo **perfil.blade.php**, **configuracion.blade.php**, **carrito.blade.php**, etc. quiero que redirecciona a **/login** si la sesión *no* está iniciada.

**Ejemplo**

En un sitio **PHP** al iniciar sesión con éxito, te redirecciona al panel del usuario, pero si no haz iniciado e intentas ingresar directo a la ruta del panel de control, no debería dejar entrar y redireccionar al login:

```
<?php session_start();
header("Cache-control: private");
header("Cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) !="admin") {
header('Location: indexe.php');
}
?>
```

Entonces, quiero hacer esto mismo usando **blade.php** de **Laravel** habiendo creado el login anteriormente con `artisan make:auth`.

Comment: Para este tipo de tareas haz uso de los middleware de Laravel, estos los puedes aplicar a las rutas por ejemplo, puedes revisar la documentacion https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware . La pregunta es un poco baga, te recomendaria que la completes con un ejemplo para que alguien te pueda dar una respuesta concreta a un problema concreto.

Comment: Añadí un ejemplo adicional.

Comment: Buenas Aace, Si estas utilizando la [`Auth` de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication) simplemente aplica el middleware `Auth` a aquellas rutas que quieras proteger, como te indicaron en la respuesta. No necesitas nada mas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eso lo puedes configurar en los middleware, que estan adentro de `app/http/middleware`, allí encontraras el archivo `Authenticate.php` y `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php`. Simplemente en la carpeta de `routes` archivo `web.php`. Crea las rutas nuevas que apunten a la vista que deseas y luego en los archivos que te acabo de mencionar cámbiales el return de las rutas que trae por defecto y coloca las rutas que acabas de crear.

### - Protegiendo rutas con el middleware auth

En caso de que solo quieras restringir las vistas lo puedes hacer con el middleware de autenticación que trae laravel por defecto, ¿Cómo?, Facil, desde las rutas, en el archivo `web.php` que esta dentro de la carpeta `routes`colocas el siguiente trozo de código:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){

     //Aquí coloca tús rutas, que solo podrán ser accedidas una vez se inicie sesión

});
```

Lo que pasara será que cuando alguien intente acceder a alguna ruta protegida, lo mandará a iniciar sesión.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero me refiero que al crear nuevas paginas como:  Perfil.blade.php, configuracion.blade.php, carrito.blade.php, etc. si la sesión NO esta iniciada, que no deje verlas.

Comment: Aace, edite mi respuesta según lo que me estas diciendo, espero pueda ayudarte